# Reading a file line by line in ksh

Tags: ksh

We use some package called Autosys and there are some specific commands of this package. I have a list of variables which i like to pass in one of the Autosys commands as variables one by one.

For example one such variable is var1, using this var1 i would like to launch a command something like this

```
autosys_showJobHistory.sh var1
```

Now when I launch the below written command, it gives me the desired output.

```
echo "var1" | while read line; do autosys_showJobHistory.sh $line | grep 1[1..6]:[0..9][0..9] | grep 24.12.2012 | tail -1 ; done
```

But if i put the var1 in a file say Test.txt and launch the same command using cat, it gives me nothing. I have the impression that command autosys_showJobHistory.sh does not work in that case.

```
cat Test.txt | while read line; do autosys_showJobHistory.sh $line | grep 1[1..6]:[0..9][0..9] | grep 24.12.2012 | tail -1 ; done
```

What I am doing wrong in the second command ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrote all of below, and then noticed your grep statement.
Recall that ksh doesn't support `..` as an indicator for 'expand this range of values'. (I assume that's your intent). It's also made ambiguous by your lack of quoting arguments to grep. If you were using syntax that the shell would convert, then you wouldn't really know what reg-exp is being sent to grep. Always better to quote argments, unless you know for sure that you need the unquoted values. Try rewriting as

```
grep '1[1-6]:[0-9][0-9]' | grep '24.12.2012'
```

Also, are you deliberately using the 'match any char' operator '.' OR do you want to only match a period char? If you want to only match a period, then you need to escape it like `\.`.

Finally, if any of your files you're processing have been created on a windows machine and then transfered to Unix/Linux, very likely that the line endings (Ctrl-MCtrl-J) (\r\n) are causing you problems. Cleanup your PC based files (or anything that was sent via ftp) with `dos2unix file [file2 ...]`.

---

If the above doesn't help, You'll have to "divide and conquer" to debug your problem.

When I did the following tests, I got the expected output

```
$ echo "var1" | while read line ; do print "line=${line}" ; done
line=var1
$ vi Test.txt
$ cat Test.txt
var1
$ cat Test.txt | while read line ; do print "line=${line}" ; done
line=var1
```

Unrelated to your question, but certain to cause comment is your use of the `cat` commnad in this context, which will bring you the UUOC award. That can be rewritten as

```
while read line ; do print "line=${line}" ; done < Test.txt
```

But to solve your problem, now turn on the shell debugging/trace options, either by changing the top line of the script (the shebang line) like

```
 #!/bin/ksh -vx
```

Or by using a matched pair to track the status on just these lines, i.e.

```
 set -vx
 while read line; do 
     print -u2 -- "#dbg: Line=${line}XX"
     autosys_showJobHistory.sh $line \
     | grep 1[1..6]:[0..9][0..9] \
     | grep 24.12.2012 \
     | tail -1 
 done  < Test.txt
 set +vx
```

I've added an extra debug step, the `print -u2 -- ....` (u2=stderror, -- closes option processing for print)
Now you can make sure no extra space or tab chars are creeping in, by looking at that output.

They shouldn't matter, as you have left your `$line` unquoted. As part of your testing, I'd recommend quoting it like `"${line}"`.

Then I'd comment out the tail and the grep lines. You want to see what step is causing this to break, right? So does the autosys_script by itself still produce the intermediate output you're expecting? Then does autosys + 1 grep produce out as expected, +2 greps, + tail? You should be able to easily see where you're loosing your output.

IHTH